# How can I refresh the Unity resources folder during runtime in order to pull the latest files (Without AssetDatabase.Refresh())?

Tags: file, unity-game-engine, resources, loading

I am creating a game in Unity for Android and I am capturing screenshots during runtime and displaying them at a later point in the same scene. However, when I try this, the pictures seem to be the outdated screenshots (from a previous session) and they will only update during runtime if I refresh the resources folder manually which I cannot do when running on Android.

I have tried other methods of loading the images such as WWW and reading from a ByteArray which also did not work. I have also used AssetDatabase.Refresh() which worked but is not available to use on Android.

Here is my Screenshot code (working as required):

```
IEnumerator CaptureIt()
    {
        string fileName = "/Screenshot" + screenshotCounter + ".png";
        string pathToSave = "Assets/Resources/Screenshots/" + fileName;
        ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);
        screenshotCounter++;
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
```

Here is my code to display the image as a sprite:

```
public void loadImage(int roundNum)
    {
        loadedSprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Screenshots/Screenshot" + roundNum);
        imageDisplay.sprite = loadedSprite;
    }
```

As I said, I expect this to load the latest instance of the screenshot taken but this will only happen if the resources folder has been refreshed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so here is how I fixed the problem:

Screenshot code:

```
IEnumerator CaptureIt()
{
    string fileName = "Screenshot" + screenshotCounter + ".png";
#if UNITY_EDITOR
    //Path for Editor
    string pathToSave = "Assets/Resources/Screenshots/" + fileName;
#elif UNITY_ANDROID
    //Path for Android
    string pathToSave = fileName;
#endif
    ScreenCapture.CaptureScreenshot(pathToSave);
    screenshotCounter++;
    yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
}
```

Dsiplay code:

```
public void loadImage(int roundNum)
{
#if !UNITY_EDITOR
    string url = Application.persistentDataPath +"/"+ "Screenshot" + roundNum + ".png";
    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes( url );
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D( 996, 2048 );
    texture.LoadImage( bytes );
    Sprite sp = Sprite.Create(texture, new Rect(0, 0, texture.width, texture.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
    imageDisplay.sprite= sp ;
#else
    StartCoroutine(loadTex("Screenshots/Screenshot" + roundNum));
    Debug.Log("sping");
#endif

IEnumerator loadTex(string filePath)
{
    ResourceRequest resourceRequest = Resources.LoadAsync<Sprite>(filePath);
    while (!resourceRequest.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("yielding 0");
        yield return 0;
    }
    Sprite sp = resourceRequest.asset as Sprite;
    Debug.Log("yield return null");
    imageDisplay.sprite = sp;
    yield return null;
}
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the `StreamingAssets` folder for this, but I'm highly doubtful that that even works on Android (I don't think you can write there at runtime). Otherwise you could switch to using `Application.persistentDataPath`.
In both cases you'd need to use another way of loading your sprites, though. like using WWW or File IO.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but it is still only working in the Editor.

Comment: StreamingAssets or persistentDataPath?

Comment: I tried both, here is my new code:

`byte[] bytes;
        bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(Application.persistentDataPath + "Screenshot" + roundNum + ".png");
        Texture2D textureToLoad = new Texture2D(996, 2048, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
        textureToLoad.LoadImage(bytes);
        Sprite sp = Sprite.Create(textureToLoad, new Rect(0, 0, textureToLoad.width, textureToLoad.height), new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f));
        imageDisplay.sprite = sp;`